# How to create an array in a class in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am trying to make a player class to better organize a set of variables relating to the player. How do I make it create an array when it creates an instance you can access in the main script?

```
class player
{
    public int HP;
    public int maxHP;
    public int damage;
    public double critChance;
    public double critMultiplier;
    public int spellCount;
    
    public player()
    {
        //make a set array that is the attacks of the player
        public string[] spells = new string[spellCount];
    }
}
```

I tried to just make an array when an instance of player is created but that didn't work. What I want is an array I can access later in the main script. Instead, it just gave me a bunch of errors.

Comment: Don't use public fields for starters. Fields are internal implementation details, even if they're public, and can change at any time. Only properties are part of a type's API. Serializers for example only serialize properties, not fields, unless explicitly configured

Comment: As for the problems here, you're trying to define a *field* inside a method. Only variables can be defined in a method. At the very least add `public string[] Spells {get;} before the constructor and set it in the constructor with `Spells=new string[someConstructorParameter];`

Comment: Next bug is that you're trying to access the `spellCount` field in the constructor, where it still has its default value, 0. This will create an empty array. If you want to specify a count when constructing the player, pass it as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need array as member of the class

```
class player
{
   public int HP;
   public int maxHP;
   public int damage;
   public double critChance;
   public double critMultiplier;
   //public int spellCount; // You dont need it here
   public string[] spells;
  
   public player()
   {
      //make a set array that is the attacks of the player
      spells = new string[spellCount];
   }
}
```

you need to pass the spellCount to the constructor , something like this

```
public player(int spellCount)
{
  //make a set array that is the attacks of the player
  spells = new string[spellCount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all access modifiers such as public, private ... ect cannot be used inside the body of a method, One of the reasons to cause that is that the properties (Attributes) part of a class is static, meaning the attributes which you define in your code cannot be added to or the opposite under any circumstances throughout the whole run-time.
So what you actually need to do is declare that array as an attribute and assign a value to it in the constructor :

```
class player
{
public int HP;
public int maxHP;
public int damage;
public double critChance;
public double critMultiplier;
public int spellCount;
public string[] spells; // here is your attribute

public player(int SpellCount)
{
    // and here goes the assignment
    this.spells = new string[SpellCount];
}
```

}

NOTE* : the assignment that i put inside the constructor can be done via a setter for example also but if you want it to happen at the moment of creating a Player object it has to be done in the constructor.